# Order custom Taxomony alphabetically and reversal after clicking a button?

Tags: taxonomy

I made a custom type named foods and a taxonomy named fruits. I want to order the fruits name alphabetically ( A-Z ) on clicking a button and then clicking on it again it will show Z-A order.

Can you tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass order parameter in url on click on link like /?order=DESC or if you are using a button then it must be submitting a form with order field value change GET to POST and field name

```
if(isset($_GET['order'])){
$order = $_GET['order'];
}
else{
$order = 'ASC';
}
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
'orderby'    => 'name',
'order'=> $order,
) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately its not working.
check out this link:

http://tjdesigners.info/mooctracks/?post_type=courses

After using each filters the url changes. 

Suppose I choose Begineer under Level, then the url changes to 
http://tjdesigners.info/mooctracks/?post_type=courses&course_levels=beginner

Now if I put  /?order=DESC it doesnt work . Can you please tell me how to make it work? 
thanks